# regex new line match inside an angle brackets

Tags: regex

I want to find all the files which uses `<Button>` component with className props in Visual studio editor.

Tried this regex `<Button.*className.*>` . It works partially. It didn't match the new line case. Kindly, check attached screenshot.

Last line button component didn't match. Because, props entered in a new line. I tried `\n`. It didn't work..

https://regex101.com/r/y2lQUf/3/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.*` to `[^>]*`. By default `.` matches everything except newline, so `.*` won't match across multiple lines.

```
<Button[^>]*className[^>]*>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xSHYQi/2)

Comment: It works fine in regex101.com.. But, it didn't work in visual studio editor.. Is anything am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, don't know why VSCode doesn't do this

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Tried this `<Button[^>]*[\n\s]+className[^>]*>` after reading this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_multiline-search) from VS. It works fine now..